# Deleting double blank lines or more in Notepad++ while retaining single blanks

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I am trying to delete blank lines in a document, but wish to keep single blanks intact. For example:

```
line 1

line 2


line 3



line 4
```

Must delete find and replace to keep a single blank line between all:

```
line 1

line 2

line 3

line 4
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- In the *Replace* dialog (<kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd>), select *Extended* Search Mode.
- For the *Find what* text, enter (for Windows carriage-return/line-feed convention to mark end of line):

  > \r\n\r\n
- For the *Replace with* text, enter

  > \r\n

Each time you click *replace All*, double CR/LF's will be converted to single, or quadruple CR/LF's to double.

The characters to enter may be changed in different circumstances, e.g. if a line has a single space, or if the CR/LF convention differs, as in Mac and Linux OS's.

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all linebreaks that are followed by 2 linebreaks, living only 2 linebreaks.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R+(?=\R{2})`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R+         : 1 or more any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=         : positive lookahead, a zero-length assertion that make sure we have after
    \R{2}   : 2 linebreaks
)           : end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
line 1

line 2

line 3

line 4
```

Comment: Note: requires blank lines to be truly empty (without any whitespace characters like tabs, spaces, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Windows solution: you could use this autohotkey script on notepad++.

Bonus: **it will work on notepad++ plus everywhere else on your computer**.

You can call it with a shortcut (alt+space here):

```
^!Space::
    clipboard =
    Send, ^a
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait
    ClipBoard := RegExReplace(ClipBoard, "\R(?=\R{2,})")
    sleep 100
    Send, ^v
    return
```